# Transforming multivariate $N(0,1)$ samples into $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ samples via matrix operations

Tags: linear-transformations, normal-distribution

I have samples from $N(0,1)$ and I wish to transform them into samples from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. All distributions are multivariate, specifically they are 2D. I know that with univariate distributions, you can simply do $y=\sigma x + \mu$ to transform a standard distribution into any other gaussian. What is the equivalent operation for transforming multivariate standard distributions? I would prefer a matrix solution $Y=A X + \mu$ where $A$ is some matrix I can easily derive from the covariance matrix.

Comment: Are samples independient between each other?

Comment: The samples are independent from each other. But there may be dependences between the components of an individual sample in the desired distribution; this would be indicated by the covariance matrix $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is multivariate normal, any affine transform $AX+b$ is also multivariate normal for constants $A,b$.  Thus,

$$Z\sim N(0,\mathbb{I}_n)\iff Z_i\overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} N(0,1)\\
\implies Y\equiv \sigma Z+\mu{\bf1}_n\sim N(\mu{\bf1}_n, \sigma^2\mathbb{I}_n)\iff Y_i\overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2),\
$$
where ${\bf1}_n$ is the $n\times 1$ column vector of ones.

---

Update: More generally, if $X\sim N(\mu_X,\Sigma_X)$, then $Y\equiv AX+b\sim N(A\mu_X+b,A\Sigma_XA').$

Comment: Do we need to use $\sigma$ as the multiplier with $Z$? That would have to be calculated as the square root of the covariance matrix. What about the Cholesky decomposition of $\sigma^2$, which for the 2D case I believe would be $$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 \\ \rho\sigma_2 & \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The above comment was based on https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/multivariate-normal-primer/#Affine-transformations-of-the-multivariate-normal

Comment: I assumed $\sigma$ and $\mu$ were scalar in your question so answered as such; let me update my answer with a more general response

Comment: And yes, using the notation from my updated remark, if $X$ was standard normal ($\mu_X=0,\Sigma_X=\mathbb{I}_n$), then a suitable $A$ needed to to obtain a positive definite covariance matrix of $Y$ given by $\Sigma_Y=AA'$ may be found via Cholesky decomposition.